# Arangodbjs query using with then() does not work IE11

Tags: javascript, promise, arangodb

I followed the default example by Arangodbjs and it is seemed that in browser which does not support Promises, this one will fail. How can we work around this?

```
db.query(queryString).then()
```

Comment: I mean arangodbjs. It is an official Javascript lib to interactive with ArangoDB for web application

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs):

> If you want to use promises in environments that don't provide the global Promise constructor, use a promise polyfill like [`es6-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise) or inject a ES6-compatible promise implementation like `bluebird` into the global scope.

Comment: I am very inexperienced but it seemed that arangodb ship with itself an promise.js. That is why I was very confused about the usage